# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column

Tags: sql-server, data-migration, identity-column

I am migrating my application form one database to other with keeping table structure as it is.  I am creating same tables in new table and inserted value using db link.
I am getting error message like "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'XYZ' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF." because table XYZ have ScreenConfigSettingAccessId as an identity column

Below is the script I am using for creating table and inserting value

```
     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XYZ](
[ScreenConfigSettingAccessId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[APP_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ScreenConfigSettingId] [int] NOT NULL,
[RSRC_ID] [char](20) NOT NULL)
)


INSERT INTO [dbo].[XYX]
       (
[ScreenConfigSettingAccessId] ,
[APP_ID] ,
[ScreenConfigSettingId] ,
[RSRC_ID] 
)
SELECT 
[ScreenConfigSettingAccessId] ,
[APP_ID] ,
[ScreenConfigSettingId] ,
[RSRC_ID] 
FROM [olddatabase].[database name].[dbo].[XYX]
```

in old table the value of ScreenConfigSettingAccessId is 3 and 4.

I want to inset the same data which old table have so set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON and tried but it still not allowing to insert.

Looking for you suggestions

Comment: Seems like it should work if you add `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.XYZ ON` just before the insert. What does the error say when you try inserting with `IDENTITY_INSERT` on?

Comment: after 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.XYZ ON ' able to insert data :-)

Comment: I need to 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.XYZ OFF ' after insert  right?

Comment: after turning off all look good to me.. thank you @ander2ed for your help

Comment: Yep, that's correct. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the table. Check out the command syntax in SQL Books Online: [SQL 2000](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(v=sql.80).aspx) or [SQL 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx%20[SQL%202014]) (the syntax hasn't changed).